# Test keeps failing for product landing page

Tags: html, css

I am currently doing Free code camp and working on the product landing page. I keep getting an error that my internal link is not working properly. The code can be found at: [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/idallenbach/pen/YzPoWjY)

```
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
<div id="logo">
<header id="header">
<img src="" id='header-img' alt="company logo">
<nav id="nav-bar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#info" class="nav-link">Product information</a></li>
<li><a href="#locate" class="nav-link">Where to find</a></li>
<li><a href="#cost" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
</div>
<a name="info"><p id="where-to-find">This is where product info can be found</p></a>
<video  id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<a name="locate"><p id="where-to-find">This is where product can be found</p></a>
<a name="cost"><p id="cost">Enter your e-mail to get a quote.</p></a>
<form action="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js" id="form">
<input   name="email"
    id="email"
    type="email"
    placeholder="Enter your email address"
    required/>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Get Started" class="btn"/>
</form>
```

The error is shown in the following screenshot. 
[Free code camp error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7SPa.png)

Answer (score 1):

All your `<a>` anchor tags nesting the `<p>` elements should have an `id` that corresponds with the nav-bar anchor links but all your anchor tags have the `name` attribute instead. Replace all the `name` attributes with `id` attributes and your 5th test should pass.

**Example:**

This:

```
<a name="info"><p id="product-information">This is where product info can be found</p></a>
```

Should be:

```
<a id="info"><p id="product-information">This is where product info can be found</p></a>
```

And this:

```
<a name="locate"><p id="where-to-find">This is where product can be found</p></a>
```

Should be:

```
<a id="locate"><p id="where-to-find">This is where product can be found</p></a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was racking my brain on this. Hopefully I will get the hang of this eventually.

Comment: @Idallenbach Glad I could help. And you're doing great so far. Keep at it!

Comment: @Idallenbach Also, do mark this as the correct answer by clicking the grey tick-mark on the side of the question if it helped you solve your problem :)